# How to add comment to single property in inline style tag with javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-chrome-extension

Let's say we have

```
<p style="background-color: rgb(219, 51, 51); color: rgb(148, 87, 87);">
     some text
</p>
```

The `<style>` tag was added with code:

```
var el = document.querySelectorAll(selector);

for(var i=0;i<el.length;i++) 
{
    el[i].style[option] = value;

}
```

All i want to do is to remove single prop, for eg. color. I tried to use `el[i].style.removeProperty('color');`, `el[i].style.setProperty(option, 'initial');` and even `el[i].style[option] = "";`, however none of this worked.
I came up with an idea, that I can simply comment out prop with value in style tag, to look like this:

```
<p style="background-color: rgb(219, 51, 51); /* color: rgb(148, 87, 87); */">
     some text
</p>
```

Do you have any idea how to write javascript function to comment out selected property with value from style tag? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You could try setting it to `null` or `'unset'`

Comment: If you could give working code snippet it would help us to help you better, Because JavaScript code part I see is not complete, selector, option, value variables are not initialized.

Answer (score 1):

Well, `el[i].style.color = ''` should do the trick, if not, something is wrong with the elements selector.